# Should Push Notifications be local, or pushed from a server

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a requirement for our app that I am not quite sure how to tackle.  Basically, we can estimate when an event will happen, and want to alert the user when the event is X minutes away (i.e. alert me 5 minutes before the train gets here).

My question is, would this be best used as a Local Notification, or a Push Notification?
If we use Local Notifications, we will need the app to call a Webservice and get the estimated event time (when the train is estimated to get to the station).  It would then need to evaluate if it should trigger the event.
Based on my understanding, if we use a Local Notification then the notification won't work when the app is suspended or unloaded from memory.

But if I use Push Notifications, I would need to run these estimates on a server and when the event is X minutes away, send a push notification to the individual users phone.  While I can do this, I worry about the scalability if we get a whole bunch of users using the app.  I.E. if I have to notify 1,000 users I would need to send 1,000 individual messages and that would take some time and resources.  I know I could use Topics, and the user could subscribe to a Topic and I would just need to send a single message to the Topic.  The problem I see with this is that I would need to create a topic for the 8 am arrival, the 9 am arrival, the 10 am arrival, etc.  This is because as a user, I only care about the 8 am arrival, and not the 9 am arrival.  And when the train schedule changes, I would need to create a new topic for each new schedule time.  This would quickly become untenable.

So am I missing something here?  How do other applications do this?  Is there something in iOS that I am missing?  My phone will give me traffic updates when I leave my home.  How is it doing this, when I don't have the traffic app open?  If it is built into the OS is it something we can replicate?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use push messaging from a server.  Sending hundreds or thousands of individual messages per second isn't a problem for Apple's infrastructure; you just need to size your server accordingly.  All push messages are sent to an individual device. There is no option for "broadcasting" on a topic.  Apple's apps (like Apple Maps) don't need to play by the same rules as your apps

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback.  I appreciate the guidance.